# Python's Struct.Pack in C#

Tags: c#, python, memorystream, pack

I am trying to reproduce the following statement in C#. As the procedure shows, **packlength** is a string packed according to the '!l' format which represents a *long value (in network byte order - big endian*).

```
packlength=struct.pack('!l', len(packetdata)+10)
```

I attempted the following:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream)) {
                    writer.Write ((long)(packetData.Length+10));
        }
}
```

Is the procedure correct? If so, how do I access the resulted "string" from the memory stream?

Answer (score 1):

C# equivalent is

```
var bytes=BitConverter.GetBytes((long)packetdata.length)
```

UPDATE:
John skeet have a very good lib for playing with byte order.check out the following link

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(
    IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((long)packetdata.length + 10)
);
```

This reads rather badly so you way wish to wrap IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder in a different class, as a static method, to improve feasibility. After all, who wants to see IPAddress when doing a host to network order conversion?

Although your Python code is using strings to hold the buffer, they are not really strings. Why you have here is a byte array and that's what the code above produces.

Comment: Note that in python  the `str` type has another name, `bytes`